# compression at bit level

Tags: python, compression

I plan to archive hours of sensor data on a file. For this sensor, the resolution (number of bits used) is perfectly known: 22 bits

My first attempt was to write a succession of 22 bits values, concatenated, as a bit stream.

And it works perfectly fine, especially when the signal is complex.
However, when the signal is highly compressible I found it more interesting to pad my items up to the next multiple of 8.

For example:

```
high_res_sinus = [int(math.sin(i) * 0x3FFFFF) & 0x3FFFFF for i in range(10000)]
low_res_sinus = [int(math.sin(i) * 0x3) & 0x3FFFFF for i in range(10000)]
```

Here, `high_res_sinus` is harder to compress (with gzip) than `low_res_sinus`

```
# size before -> after gzip compression (ratio)
high_res_sinus:22 bits: 27500 -> 27528 (100.1 %) # 22 bits
high_res_sinus:24 bits: 30000 -> 29300 (97.7 %) # same, padded to 24 bits
low_res_sinus:22 bits: 27500 -> 1104 (4.0 %) # 22 bits
low_res_sinus:24 bits: 30000 -> 374 (1.2 %) # same, padded to 24 bits
low_res_sinus:32 bits: 40000 -> 338 (0.8 %) # same, padded to 32 bits, even better !
```

https://code.activestate.com/recipes/580649-nbitarray/

For the `high_res_sinus` the 22 bits values, concatenated, is the best option, uncompressed !
But for the `low_res_sinus`, its much better to compress the padded version.

Would you know a compressor where the resolution can be set to a value different to modulo 8 ?
Would you have a better suggestion ?

---

**EDIT**

About a better suggestion : I found that a combination of hdf5 with mafisc filter work very well for sensor data. Even if I like to re-invent the wheel :)

Comment: So you are saying, the more you pad a lower resolution signal, the better the relative or the better the absolute compression? Do you get a smaller file if you pad more?

Comment: from what I tried : 24 work better than 22, 32 better than 24... then nothing good until 64 which also gives a good compression size but not better than 32 :) (with 61 bits padding -> 2443 bytes compressed, with 64 -> 541)

Comment: Yes, there are advantages with alignment in memory in multiples of 8. So this must be specific to the compression that gzip does. Very interesting observation!

Comment: When you pad the bit count up to a multiple of 8, all the extra bits are zero (presumably), so there's more redundancy in the data for the gzip compressor to eliminate. Of course that only holds up to the point where the overhead of having all those extra zero bits is greater than the additional compression being achieved by adding them.

Comment: and that's why I was looking for a compressor able to handle arbitrary sized chunks of data (here 22 bits) to focus only on the meaningful redundancy :) Clearly, the problem here is to be redundant over a 22 bit pattern that the compressor don't see with its 8 bit goggles

Answer (score 1):

Usually a good model for the next sensor sample is the last sensor sample. You should look at differencing the samples and then compressing. You send the first sample as is. Each subsequent sample is sent as that sample minus the previous sample. To aid in compression, you would then store each difference as a variable number of bytes, using the high bit of each byte to indicate if there is another byte. Ideally most of your samples would end up as one byte. Then you can apply deflate (gzip) or some other lossless compressor.

An encoding is the least significant seven bits of the difference with the high bit as a one if this is all of the bits, or a zero if there are more bits in the next byte. And so on until you get all the bits, terminated by a high bit of one.

Comment: nice trick :) I loose the ability to do random access (compared to 22bits packed data) but still interesting. Let's implement it and see.